# android notifyDataSetChanged not working if delete item from data item

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter, notifydatasetchanged

I am developing an android application in which I am using one base adapter and displaying data in list form.Now what happened If I remove any object from list and if I call `notifyDataSetChanged`, its not working as expected. I tried this in following manner.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    shareDataList = getData();
    shareListAdapter = new SharedHistoryListAdapter(this, shareDataList);
    sharedList.setAdapter(shareListAdapter);

}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{

     super.onResume();

    // after deleting data it is coming inside onresume ... 

    shareDataList = getData();

    shareListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

I checked data size inside my activity and inside adapter as well. So in activity it is showing count as expected but inside adapter it is not showing updated count. Am I missing something? Need some help.

Comment: where are you deleting the item?

Comment: Its list view and it has detail view as well. So inside detail view tat is my new activity I am deleting data from that list. If I update any data item it is showing updated data but only thing if I remove from it then it is not working properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot change the reference of the list after setting the list to the adapter. so remove the line

```
 shareDataList = getData();
```

and replace with

```
    shareDataList.clear();
    shareDataList.addAll(getData());
```

and now invoke the `shareListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Thank you for quick replay. Its working properly. Such a stupid mistake. Thank you for help.

Comment: But I have one short query. If I am setting some data for list inside oncreate. And again doing notify data set change inside onresume. will it cause performance while loading for that first time when it executes both oncreate and onresume?

Comment: It will not cause performance problems for this minor changes.

Answer (score 1):

I think, in getData() method gets every time new ArrayList object.
You should simply call

```
shareListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

it will work perfectly